# Saving logon information when loading Crystal Report in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I created a Crystal Report that can run fine but it needs enter logon information . I googled and find this code but it did not work for me. Any suggestion with code will be highly appreciated.

```
private void frmPrintWIPReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
    var crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    Tables CrTables;

    cryRpt.Load("rptWIP.rpt");

    crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "192.168.40.253";
    crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "TNET";
    crConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    crConnectionInfo.UserID = "sa";
    crConnectionInfo.Password = "******";

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
    foreach (Table CrTable in CrTables)
    {
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
    }

    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
    crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: What exactly 'doesn't work'? Any exception? Error message? Empty rows?

Comment: It required logon when we open this report! I need no logon dialog appear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. I hope it is same as your need.

```
private void frmPrintWIPReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        var crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
        var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        Tables CrTables;

        cryRpt.Load("rptWIP.rpt");

        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo()
            {
                ServerName = @"192.168.40.253",
                DatabaseName = @"TNET",
                UserID=@"sa",
                Password=@"******"                
               //IntegratedSecurity = true
            };

        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
        foreach (Table CrTable in CrTables)
        {
            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
        }

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
    }
```